# String value from a field of custom Object List

Tags: apex, class, list, string

Please let me know how can I put a field values in a string from below List.

```
oIncs = [SELECT Id , 
                Name , 
                No_Of_Transactions_abv__c , 
                OwnerId , 
                recordtype.developername,
                Rep_abv__c , 
                Status_abv__c , 
                Attested_By_abv__c , 
                Publish_Date_abv__c, 
                External_Id_abv__c  
           FROM Compliance_Incident_abv__c  
          WHERE Id in :recIds];


String Str= oIncs.recordtype.developername // I need something like this
```

Error:   Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List. This is the error I get. It is on line "String Str= oIncs.recordtype.developername;"

Comment: not clear from your question what you want to achive. Will you please elaborate?

Comment: I have updated my question. I need to assign value of recordtype.developername from above query that return only one record to String Str

Comment: Try RecordType.Name instead of recordtype.developername

Comment: What error are you currently receiving?

Comment: Probably a concrete sobject error since olncs is a list

Comment: ... and that `Id in :recIds`...

Comment: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Compliance_Incident_abv__c>. This is the error I get. It is on line "String Str= oIncs.recordtype.developername;"

Comment: @Eric  Yes , can you please guide me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but guessing this can be an iissue.

Seems like you are using list here `oIncs`

```
String Str= oIncs[0].recordtype.developername;
```

---

```
List<Compliance_Incident_abv__c> oIncs = [SELECT Id , 
                Name , 
                No_Of_Transactions_abv__c , 
                OwnerId , 
                recordtype.developername,
                Rep_abv__c , 
                Status_abv__c , 
                Attested_By_abv__c , 
                Publish_Date_abv__c, 
                External_Id_abv__c  
           FROM Compliance_Incident_abv__c  
          WHERE Id in :recIds];

String Str = '';
if(!oIncs.isEmpty()){
    Str = oIncs[0].recordtype.developername;
}
```

For a side note pls add completed code in question